# What changes brought into DSM-5 have increased therapeutic use of medications?

Tags: clinical-psychology

Given the controversies surrounding DSM-5, has there been any research into its impact on prescription practice (in the United States)?

If so, what are the changes that have resulted in increased use of medications?

Comment: Given that DSM-V was released in 2013, and insurers probably did not start accepting its diagnostic names or multiaxial system (without concurrent references to DSM-IV) until somewhat later, research on this would be quick work indeed!

Comment: @Krysta - at least some work on DSM-V is underway - http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25372242 - one result of a quick search through PubMed. Not drug-related, though. You have a point, and this could be an answer (or indeed **the** answer for now).

Comment: I feel this question is very broad as it can pertain to any of the many many different diagnoses criteria within the DSM.  The changes to diagnostic criteria could reduce the numbers in diagnosing some mental health problems as some could increase numbers.  Are you interested in any particular mental health issue?  Depression perhaps?